# PHP Redirect with GET

Tags: php, html, mysql

`<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {`

```
if (isset($_GET['type'])) {
    switch ($_GET['type']) {
        case 'big':
            header('Location: HOME');
            // Query can be executed here...
            exit;
        break;
```

`?>`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <a href="?type=big">
                <div class="col-md-6 big">
                    <h1>Big</h1>
```

Those are my two sets of code. The PHP and the HTML. However whenever i click on the picture. The URL becomes http://WEBSITE/rooms?type=big , however it doesnt do the redirect part where it's meant to go to the ''home'' page.

My web.config for this is currently

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 6" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^rooms([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url=rooms&amp;type={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the absolute path?

Comment: can't you use "index.php"?

Comment: I'm a beginner with PHP. however i want a query to be executed too before the redirect. So if you have any suggestions I'd love to see. I cant use it under index.php because thats already in use.

Comment: With only that set of codes it's going to be hard to tell what's wrong. Are they in separate files? What's `HOME` supposed to mean? Do you have htaccess in your website? Also, take a look at [How do I get PHP Errors to display?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: @FirstOne The error is to do with the web.config. I will upload what my web.config is for that certain rule on the main post.

Answer (score 0):

try: `header("Refresh:0; url=index.php");`

Comment: doesn't work. Still comes up with  ?type=big and does nothing. Thanks for trying though.